# POST не ловит значение value из списка option

Tags: post, php

Форма:

```
<form method="post" action="search.php">
<input type="text" name="search" id="search_box" class='search_box'/>
 <select id="selectbasic" name="where" class="input-xlarge">
  <option value="0" selected="selected">Везде</option>
  <option value="4">Скрипты</option>
  <option value="5">Программы</option>
  <option value="6">Для телефона</option>
  <option value="7">Видео</option>
  <option value="8">Аудио</option>
<option value="9">Книги</option>
<option value="10">Ключи</option>
<option value="11">Дизайн</option>
<option value="12">Остальное</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Поиск" class="search_button" />
</form>
```

php

```
$s_where = $_POST['where'];
echo $s_where;
```

реакции 0, ничего не выводит, по идее должен выводить value, 4 например. Что делать?

Comment: измени name="where" на name="where[]"

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/349625/как-передать-значение-select-в-php?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=349634#349634

Comment: @rnddev и как именно это поможет?

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)` сделайте

Comment: Бред однако, не работает

Comment: @Rammsteinik, ваш [код полностью рабочий][1]. Проблема где-то в другом месте. Включите вывод всех ошибок и предупреждений.

   [1]:http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/5huc-mvpk

Comment: у меня работает, и это главное

Comment: @rnddev отличная аргументация! Попробуйте сказать такое тимлиду, выложив нерабочий код на боевой сервер.